# Create a function/forloop that compares each x to all y's

Tags: r, function

I have this function that shows me whether number a is equal to or closer to zero than number b where 1 = yes, and 0 = no:

```
f <- function(a,b){

  if(((b<0)&(a>= b)&(a<=-b))|((b>0)&(a<= b)&(a>=-b)))
  {
    print(1)
  }
 else
 {
  print(0)
 }
```

}

The end goal is to determine the probability a single number a is closer to zero than all the b's.

Example:

```
a  b  prob
1  3   100% (a is equidistant or closer to zero than 5/5 b's)
2  2   60% (a is equidistant or closer to zero than 3/5 b's)
3  1   20% (a is equidistant or closer to zero than 1/5 b's)
4  1    0% (a is equidistant or closer to zero than 0/5 b's)
5  2    0% (a is equidistant or closer to zero than 0/5 b's)
```

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to change the function or create a forloop so that it doesn't calculate row by row and instead, for each a, it spits out a 1 or 0 for all values of b. After that, I can easily add the 1's together and divide by the total number of observations to get the probability for each a.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `ifelse`, which vectorizes the input and output

```
f <- function(a, b) ifelse(((b < 0)&(a >= b)&(a <= -b))|((b > 0)&(a <= b)&(a >= -b)), 1, 0)

f(rnorm(10), rnorm(10))
#> [1] 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1
```

Though as @MauritsEvers points out, just doing the logical test itself and coercing to a numeric vector is another option here:

```
f <- function(a, b) 1 * (((b < 0) & (a >= b) & (a <= -b)) | ((b > 0) & (a <= b) & (a >= -b)))
```

Comment: No need for `ifelse` here; you can convert the boolean expression to `integer` with `as.integer` or (using unary `+`). Example: Compare `ifelse(mtcars$cyl > 5, 0, 1)` with `+(!mtcars$cyl > 5)`. Among other (bad) things, `ifelse` is slow, so it's generally good to avoid it if you can.

Comment: For a number `a` and a vector `b`, `f = function(a, b) mean(a < abs(b))` will give the fraction of `b`'s for which `a` is closer to zero.